# express + angularjs : app hangs on invalid url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I am facing a weird issue with angular and express,

I have a very simple routing on app.js as below :

```
    app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

    app.get('*', routes.index);
```

also this is on my angular routerprovider :

```
 $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/home'
  }).
  when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/contact'
  }).
  otherwise({
    templateUrl: '/partials/error'
  });
```

now the problem is, if I enter below invalid url, it goes to error page [OK]

```
  http://www.devnest.io/someInvalidpath  // it will go to /partials/error
```

But if I enter an invalid url with two level path (or more) page will hang [NOT OK]

```
  http://www.devnest.io/someInvalidpath/AnotherInvalidPath  // page will hang without error
```

and in the developer tools, it likes infinite loop and page call, like this picture :

[image]

also there is no error on node.js or angular ...

I am really confused, can anyone help me, on which part my routing is not correct ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.use(routes.index);
```

instead of

```
app.get('*', routes.index);
```